# how to send a file into clipboard from command line (CLI)?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, clipboard

I expect something simple like "put2clip c:\boot.ini" which would result in the same thing as right-clicking in explorer the boot.ini file and select 'copy'.

i looked at nirsoft's nircmd, thinkingms.com/pensieve/2009/03/14/ClipexeACommandLineToolForTheWindowsClipboard.aspx and steve.org.uk/Software/clipboard/ bot none of them seems to do the work or provide good documentation.

thanks.

Comment: update: I've received an email from Roshan James author of alternate clip.exe but the procedure and syntax is quite a pain:
cd myfolder first, then
clip files filename.exe copy

Answer (score 18):

You don't specify which flavour of Windows, but anything from Vista/2003 onwards should work doing this:

```
echo blah | clip
```

or

```
type myTextFile.txt | clip
```

However, I am not aware of a way to put an *object* (like a file (jpg, mp3, ini, etc)) into the clipboard from the command line using native tools.

Comment: Works, but not for all character sets.  I was trying to get ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ into a file so I could quickly get it to my clipboard, but `type shruggie.txt` produces ┬»\_(πâä)_/┬»

I don't know what the rant above is about ...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MayTheSForceBeWithYou Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48029600/159145 (interestingly, also using the exact same emoticon as your comment...)

Answer (score 2):

"simple command line tool to copy file into windows clipboard"
See: https://github.com/rostok/file2clip

It includes source.